# Simultaneous recursive tree traversal?

Tags: python, recursion

I was given a binary tree and was asked to invert that tree.

```
     4
   /   \
  2     7
 / \   / \
1   3 6   9
```

to

```
     4
   /   \
  7     2
 / \   / \
9   6 3   1
```

The code as follows,

```
def invertTree(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return None
    root.left, root.right = self.invertTree(root.right), self.invertTree(root.left)
    return root
```

I understand that when we have assignments like `x,y = y,x`
The action of assign `y` to `x` and `x` to `y` happens **simultaneously**.

**My question is:**

When we have two recursions `self.invertTree(root.right)` and `self.invertTree(root.left)`, what's the order of traversal? How can we make two recursions happen simultaneously?

Comment: What do you mean "happen simultaneously?" Do you want them to happen in parallel threads?

Comment: They are not happening simulataneously. `self.invertTree(root.right)` is executed first, and then `self.invertTree(root.left)`. Thereafter the return values are assigned to root.left and root.right respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a,b = b,a
```

is just a shortcut to swap values without having to use a temp variable

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

In your code, the recursions are not happening simulataneously. `self.invertTree(root.right)` is executed first, and then `self.invertTree(root.left)`. Thereafter the return values are assigned to `root.left` and `root.right` respectively. Probably the below code is easier to read and understand, but does the same thing

```
temp = root.left
root.left = self.invertTree(root.right)
root.right = self.invertTree(temp)
```